Vision Transformer model training and Validation accuracy stuck at 50
I have built Vision Transformers from scratch using Tensorflow keras for Binary classification of Fake and Real images.The dataset is balanced, 50% Real images and 50% fake images. But when i run this model, the training as well as validation accuracy is stuck at 0.5000. This is my code :
class MultiHeadedAttention(Layer):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dims, no_head):
        super(MultiHeadedAttention, self).__init__(name="MultiHeadSelfAttentionBlock")
        self.embedding_dims = embedding_dims
        self.no_head = no_head
        if embedding_dims % no_head != 0:
            print(f'embedding dimensions : {embedding_dims} should be divisible by number of heads : {no_head}')
        self.query = Dense(embedding_dims)
        self.key = Dense(embedding_dims)
        self.value = Dense(embedding_dims)
        self.projections_dims = embedding_dims // no_head
        self.combined_heads = Dense(embedding_dims)
        
    def attention_block(self, query, key, value):
        
        score = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b = True)
        dim_key = tf.cast(tf.shape(key)[-1],  tf.float32)
        scaled_score = score/tf.math.sqrt(dim_key)
        weights = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_score, axis=-1)
        output = tf.matmul(weights, value)
        return output, weights
    
    def separate_heads(self, x, batch_size):
        x = tf.reshape(
                        x, 
                        (batch_size, -1, self.no_head, self.projections_dims)
                    )
        return tf.transpose(
                                x,
                                perm=[0,2,1,3]
                            )
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        
        batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        query_vector = self.query(inputs)
        key_vector = self.key(inputs)
        value_vector = self.value(inputs)
        
        query_vector = self.separate_heads(query_vector, batch_size)
        key_vector = self.separate_heads(key_vector, batch_size)
        value_vector = self.separate_heads(value_vector, batch_size)
        
        attention, weights = self.attention_block(query_vector, key_vector, value_vector)
        attention = tf.transpose(attention, perm=[0,2,1,3])
        concat_attention = tf.reshape(attention, (batch_size, -1, self.embedding_dims))
        output = self.combined_heads(inputs=concat_attention)
        return output

class TransformerBlock(Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, no_head, embedding_dims, mlp_dim, dropout):
        super(TransformerBlock,self).__init__(name="TransformerBlock")
        
        self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)

        self.mul_attention = MultiHeadedAttention(embedding_dims , no_head)
        self.mlp = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                Dense(mlp_dim, activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu),
                Dropout(dropout),
                Dense(embedding_dims),
                Dropout(dropout)
            ]
        )
        
        self.dropout1 = Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout2 = Dropout(dropout)
        
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        
        inputs_norm = self.layernorm1(inputs)
        attention_output = self.mul_attention(inputs_norm)
        attention_output = self.dropout1(attention_output)
        out = attention_output + inputs
        out_norm = self.layernorm2(out)
        mlp_output = self.mlp(out_norm)
        mlp_output = self.dropout2(mlp_output)
        
        return mlp_output + out
        
class VisionTransformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(
                    self,
                    image_size,
                    patch_size,
                    embedding_dims,
                    no_head,
                    mlp_dim,
                    no_layers,
                    dropout,
                    num_class,
                    channels
                ):
        
        super(VisionTransformer, self).__init__(name="VisionTransformer")
        
        self.num_patches = (image_size//patch_size)**2
        self.patch_dim = channels * patch_size ** 2
        self.patch_size = patch_size
        self.embedding_dims = embedding_dims
        self.no_layers = no_layers
        self.rescale = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(scale=1./255)
        self.pos_emb = self.add_weight(
            name="pos_emb", shape=(1, self.num_patches + 1, embedding_dims)
        )
        self.class_emb = self.add_weight(name="class_emb", shape=(1, 1, embedding_dims))
        self.patch_proj = Dense(embedding_dims)
        self.enc_layers = [
                                TransformerBlock(no_head, embedding_dims, mlp_dim, dropout)
                                for _ in range(no_layers)
                            ]
        self.mlp_head = tf.keras.Sequential(
                                                [
                                                    # tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),                                                    
                                                    tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6),
                                                    Dense(mlp_dim, activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu),
                                                    Dropout(dropout),
                                                    Dense(num_class, activation='sigmoid')
                                                ]
        
        
                                            )
        
    def extract_patches(self, images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID",
        )
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, self.patch_dim])
        return patches
        
    def call(self, x):
        
        batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
        x = self.rescale(x)
        patches = self.extract_patches(x)
        x = self.patch_proj(patches)
        class_emb = tf.broadcast_to(
            self.class_emb, [batch_size, 1, self.embedding_dims]
        )
        # print("Shape of x = ", tf.shape(x))
        # print("Shape of class_emb = ", tf.shape(class_emb))

        x = tf.concat([class_emb, x], axis=1)
        x = x + self.pos_emb
        

        for layer in self.enc_layers:

            x = layer(x)
        x = self.mlp_head(x[:, 0]
        return x



dataset = pd.read_csv("celebdf_images_data.csv")

traindf, valdf = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=0.2)
for index, value in traindf['label'].value_counts().items():
    print(index, value)

batch_size = 4

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    # rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=False,  # Typically not used for mammography
    fill_mode='nearest'
    )
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=traindf,
    x_col='image_paths',
    y_col='label',
    target_size=(256, 256),  # adjust this to the size of your images
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'  # use 'categorical' for multi-class problems
)

valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    # rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=False,  # Typically not used for mammography
    fill_mode='nearest'
    )

valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=valdf,
    x_col='image_paths',
    y_col='label',
    target_size=(256, 256),  # adjust this to the size of your images
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'  # use 'categorical' for multi-class problems
)


model =  VisionTransformer(
                                image_size = 256,
                                patch_size = 16,
                                embedding_dims = 768,
                                no_head = 16,
                                mlp_dim = 3072,
                                no_layers = 16,
                                dropout = 0.1,
                                num_class = 1,
                                channels = 3
                            )

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=3e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=5, validation_data=valid_generator)

I tried increasing and decreasing the number of transformer encoders (no_layers), mlp_dim, no_head, embedding_dims, patch_size, etc. But nothing happened, both training and validation accuracy are stuck at 0.5000

maybe you should ask on similar portal DataScience and CrossValidated
